# React Hook test with useState for internal state

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I've been researching lots of resources for testing the internal state by using useState with React Hook but still cannot find a satisfied answer, some of the test cases are grabbing the expected value from `mount` or `shallow` which would be display on UI side but not from the internal state (`useState`) of component, what if the component does not expose the state value on UI side, for example :

```
const TestComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <span>
      <button id="count-up" type="button" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Count Up</button>
    </span>
  );
}
```

How could I write a test case to test

1) When the component mount, my internal state `count` would be initialized as 0?

2) When the component simulate an `onClick` event on button `count-up`, that my `setCount` should being called and my internal state `count` should become 1?

Comment: it'd be easier if you move the hooks into a separate file, and then we can test the hook itself separately (e.g. using the library like https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library). If you want to test the hook that is tied to a component, best way to test IMO, is to simulate click and check the result directly.

Comment: @JeeMok, Hi do you have an example that I can refer? I am not sure which part should be moved to separate file as you can see my component is already pretty small though...

Comment: @JeeMok `useState` hook is part of React, it's already in a separate file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `jest.spyOn` on React to see if the component calls the `setState` hook, for a simple test example:

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./app";
import Enzyme, { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("App", () => {
  it("should call setState with initial values on component mount", () => {
    const mockSetState = jest.spyOn(React, "useState");

    shallow(<App />);

    expect(mockSetState).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockSetState).toHaveBeenCalledWith(5);
  });
});
```

You can also move the `useState` into a separate file and use it as a custom hook (might be an unnecessary layer, so up to you)

```
// useCounter.js
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";

const useCounter = initialValue => {
  const [count, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const setCount = useCallback(x => setValue(x), []);
  return { count, setCount };
};

export default useCounter;
```

```
// usage: app.js
function App() {
  const { count, setCount } = useCounter(5);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Testing React Hooks</h1>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and then you can have your test for the "custom" hook:

```
import { renderHook, act } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import useCounter from "./useCounter";

test("should increment counter", () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useCounter(0));

  act(() => {
    result.current.setCount(1);
  });

  expect(result.current.count).toEqual(1);
});
```

Working example on Code Sandbox

[image: Edit Testing React Hooks]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed tutorial! This might be a separate issue. 
For the first way, when I use `shallow(<App />)` and check the snapshot, it always shows `null`, and my `expect(mockSetState).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` failed and it received `0`, do you have any experience or knowledge of such issue?

Comment: Enzyme might not be the best tool to test against snapshot, `shallow` and `mount` are useful to check props and trigger events and lifecycles. To test snapshot, maybe you want to try `react-test-renderer` library? There is a simple explanation here to understand about Enzyme methods and the difference and when to use which: https://gist.github.com/fokusferit/e4558d384e4e9cab95d04e5f35d4f913